# How to accomplish JOIN with two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine two queries into one so that I may use the data retrieved from both tables from only one variable.

### queries

there are two tables: **articles** and **article_tags**

```
public function latestArticles()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles       
                               WHERE article_uid = article_uid
                               ORDER BY article_uid DESC");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $row;
}

public function articleTags()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT a.*, b.*
                               FROM articles a, article_tags b
                               WHERE b.article_id = a.article_uid
                               ");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch();
    return $row;
}
```

I am unable to combine both functions into one foreach so I've been suggested to use JOIN to make it more efficient and faster. I apologize for not including what I have tried, for the last three hours they all concluded in failure.

Comment: Remove WHERE from the first query.And you are trying to combine eight rows with potential many more rows.In fact your second query already incorporates the first.

Comment: What material have you read on the theory of database table joins? What do you understand about it? What don't you understand about it? What is your question? SO is not a code generator.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    table1.col1
,   table2.col2
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function latestArticlesWithTags()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM articles a
                               LEFT JOIN article_tags b on a.article_uid = b.article_id
                               ORDER BY article_uid DESC ");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $row;
}
```

But this isn't going to work unless the tags table is 1 to 1 with the articles table, which I really doubt. If it's many tags to one article you're going to just get the first tag row it can match. You can reverse the query like this:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM article_tags b
                           LEFT JOIN articles a on a.article_uid = b.article_id
                           ORDER BY article_uid DESC");
```

But then you'll end up with a bunch of duplicated articles along with it's match tag:

```
| Aritcle   | Tag   |
| Article 1 | Tag 1 |
| Article 1 | Tag 2 |
| Article 1 | Tag 3 |
```

A better solution is probably not to return all articles in the first query and then page your results. Or to perhaps cache the tags as searlized data along side the articles so that displaying them just takes desearlizing instead of another query.

Also while these queries aren't terribly efficient (never use `*`, always explicitly set the columns to return so only the needed data is loaded) you probably are not taking a performance hit from this unless it's being run an awful lot.